# What parts are include with this light blue bike?

Tags: piece-information

I need to find the part numbers of parts on this bike.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Top](http://brickset.com/parts/6070380)
- [Frame](http://brickset.com/parts/6055651)
- [Rim (x2)](http://brickset.com/parts/4590443)
- [Tyre (x2)](http://brickset.com/parts/6064174)
- [Light](http://brickset.com/parts/3005740)